Preterito Indefinido in reported speech
When, in reported speech, Preterito Indefinido changes to Pluscuamperfecto and when it does not change?
Some tables show only Pluscuamperfecto and some show that both are correct.
Juan: "Compré un traje" -> "Juan dijo que había comprado un traje" o "Juan dijo que compró un traje"

What tables are you referring to? It's better if you include a link or at least a reference to what tables are you talking about, so the interested can check by themselves such tables.

The "pluscuamperfecto" sounds better than the "indefinido" (now called "perfecto simple"), which can only work well in colloquial language if the action immediately precedes the time it is reported:
A: ¡Acabo de comprar un traje!
B: ¿Qué te dijo A?
C: Me dijo que compró un traje.
Otherwise, the "pluscuamperfecto" will always be superior.
